# Stuck at counting array elements greater than x in an array in C/MPI

Tags: c, mpi

So, I have this problem where I have an array and I must find the count of numbers that are greater than the number of index `k` in my array. So I implemented a master-worker strategy where I have a master that takes care of the I/O and split the work to the workers. In the master thread I have created the array in a matrix-like shape, so I could pass the sub-arrays easily to the workers (I know this sounds weird). Then also in the master thread I read all the values from the input to my sub-arrays and set the `comp` (comparison value) to the value of the  `k` index value.

Then I pass the work portion size, the value for comparison and work data around to all the threads (including the master that gets its share of work). Finally, every worker do its job and report its result to the master, that while receiving the data from the workers will add their values to its own and then print the total result on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[]){
    int rank, psize;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &args);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &psize);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    int *workvet, worksize, comp;
    
    if(rank == 0){

        int tam, k;
        int **subvets, portion;

        scanf("%d", &tam);
        scanf("%d", &k);
        
        portion = ceil((float)tam/(float)psize);

        subvets = malloc(sizeof(int) * psize);
        for(int i = 0; i < psize; i++)
            subvets[i] = calloc(portion, sizeof(int));
        for(int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < portion; j++){
                if((i*j+j) < tam)
                    scanf("%d ", &subvets[i][j]);
                if((i*j+j) == k)
                    comp = subvets[i][j];
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 1; i < psize; i++){
            MPI_Send(&portion, 1, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&comp, 1, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(subvets[i], portion, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        workvet = calloc(portion, sizeof(int));
        workvet = subvets[0];
        worksize = portion;
    } else {

        MPI_Recv(&worksize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&comp, 1, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        workvet = calloc(worksize, sizeof(int));
        MPI_Recv(workvet, worksize, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }

    int maior = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < worksize; i++){
        if(workvet[i] > comp)
            maior++;
    }
    
    if(rank == 0){
        int temp;
        for(int i = 1; i < psize; i++){
            MPI_Recv(&temp, 1, MPI_INT, i, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            maior += temp;
        }
        printf("%d números maiores que %d", maior, comp);
    } else {
        MPI_Send(&maior, 1, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

My problem is that it looks like its stuck in a loop, and when trying to debug I put an `printf` in the main `for` that does the comparison in the sub-arrays and did infinite printing, however, when I put the same print anywhere else in the code, it won't be printed. I don't have any idea where I'm failing and have no idea on how I can debug my code.

Input data:

```
10 // size
7  // k
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 // elements
```

So, my program should count how many elements are greater than the element of index 7, which corresponds to the value 8, and this should return 2 in this case.

Comment: For starters, `tam` is used _uninitialized_ [from `-Wall`], so `portion` will not be quite what you'd expect (i.e. random).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @CraigEstey, I messed things up on that part of the code, but still didn't work as expected =/. What does this `-Wall` do?

Comment: Same error than in your previous question. Counts are in elements, not bytes.

Comment: `-Wall` is an option you give to the compiler to enable _all_ [well, most] warnings. Add `-Wextra` [more warnings] and `-Werror` [tells compiler to treat warnings as errors]. You should _always_ use these. They can save a _ton_ of debugging at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comment re. `tam` being *unitialized*.

There are a number of additional issues ...

You're doing `scanf` to get a value for `comp`, but in the loops below it, you're *assigning* a new value to it (i.e. the prompted value is being trashed). That may be perfectly fine if the original value is treated as a default [*if* the loop fails to assign a new value], but it seems a bit rickety to me.

AFAICT, you are trying to loop on `workvet` in *all* processes. But, for the client ones, this does *nothing* because you don't send back the result [see below].

The clients are sending back `maior` but they never compute a value for it. And, main does *not* receive that value. It computes one of its own.

`maior` has no definition in your posted code. And, therefore is *unitialized* [even in main].

It looks like you *want* the clients to send back a single *scalar* value of *their* computed value of `maior`, but they do *no* calculation for it.

Thus, the clients send back a garbage `maior` value that the main process tries to sum.

You're sending `portion` to the clients, but they receive it as `worksize`. And, after main sends it, it assigns `portion` to `worksize`. I'd recommend using the same name in all places to reduce some confusion.

You've not provided any sample data so it's hard to debug this further here. Part of the problem is that only *some* of the values in `subvets` are initialized with the `scanf` in main, based on the `if` [or so it appears ...].

So, the clients will loop over possibly unitialized values in the given `subvets` array [sent to the client which receives it as `workvet`].

If the setup loops for `subvets` are correct as far as which values to send (that is, only certain selected values should be sent), I'm not sure you can do what you want with the 2D array method you have.

Without a problem statement describing the input data and what you want to do with it, it's difficult to divine what would be the correct code, but ...

A few guesses ...

You're calculating `highest` in all processes [probably useless in main], but then *nobody* does anything with it. My guess is that you want to calculate this in the *client* processes *only*. And, send this back to main as `maior`.

Then, main can sum the `maior` values from all the clients?

---

**UPDATE:**

> I actually changed `maior` to `highest` to post the issue here, so it would make a bit of sense (maior is greater in portuguese) but failed to do so for all instances

As I mentioned, I guessed as much -- no worries. *Side note:* In fact, your English is quite good. And, it was nice of you to translate the code. Some others post in English, but leave the code in their native language. This can slow things down a bit. Sometimes, I've put the code into Google translate just to try to make sense of it.

> I just updated the code without the translation to reflect what I'm working on. So, for the subvets part I actually thought of this being a matrix, where I would send each of its lines as being one array to each of the worker threads, and the if statement is there to only read up until the size of the array has been reached, thus, leaving the rest of the values as 0 (because I used calloc, thus making this approach fit to the problem I have to solve)

There's really no need for a 2D array. Just fill a 1D array, and then give each worker different offsets and counts into that single array [see below].

By trying to do everything in a single function `main`, this is probably what caused some of the problems with separating main and worker tasks.

By splitting things up into [more] functions, this can make things easier. We can use the same variable names in master and worker for the same data without any naming conflicts.

Also, a good maxim ... *Don't replicate code*

The various `MPI_*` calls take a lot of parameters because they're general purpose. Isolating them to wrapper functions can make things simpler and debugging easier.

Note that the second argument to `MPI_Send/MPI_Recv` is a *count* and *not* number of bytes (hence, *not* `sizeof`) (i.e. a bug). By putting them in wrapper functions, the call could be fixed *once* in a single place.

I did make a slight change to the split logic. In your code [AFAICT] you were having the main/master process do some of the calculation. That's fine but I prefer to have the main process available as a control process and not encumbered by much data calculation. So, in my version, *only* the worker processes actually process the array.

Sometimes it helps to isolate the calculation algorithm/logic from the `MPI` code. I did this below by putting it in a function `docalc`. This allowed the adding of a diagnostic cross check at the end.

Anyway, below it the code. It's been heavily refactored and has many comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>

// _dbgprt -- debug print
#define _dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf("%d: ",myrank); \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    _dbgprt(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

int myrank;                         // current rank
int numproc;                        // number of processes in comm group

// dataload -- read in the data
int *
dataload(FILE *xfsrc,int worksize)
{
    int *workvet;

    // get enough space
    workvet = calloc(worksize,sizeof(int));

    // fill the array
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < worksize;  ++idx)
        fscanf(xfsrc,"%d",&workvet[idx]);

    return workvet;
}

// docalc -- count number of values greater than limit
int
docalc(int *workvet,int worksize,int k)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < worksize; ++idx) {
        if (workvet[idx] > k)
            count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}

// sendint -- send some data
void
sendint(int rankto,int *data,int count)
{
    int tag = 0;

    // NOTE: second argument is an array _count_ and _not_ the number of bytes
    MPI_Send(data,count,MPI_INT,rankto,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

// recvint -- receive some data
void
recvint(int rankfrom,int *data,int count)
{
    int tag = 0;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Recv(data,count,MPI_INT,rankfrom,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
}

// worker -- perform all worker operations
void
worker(void)
{
    int master = 0;

    // get array count
    int worksize;
    recvint(master,&worksize,1);

    // get limit value
    int k;
    recvint(master,&k,1);

    // allocate space for data
    int *workvet = calloc(worksize,sizeof(int));

    // get that data
    recvint(master,workvet,worksize);

    // calculate number of elements higher than limit
    int count = docalc(workvet,worksize,k);

    // send back result
    sendint(master,&count,1);
}

// master -- perform all master operations
void
master(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int isfile;
    FILE *xfsrc;
    int workrank;

    // get the data either from stdin or from a file passed on the command line
    do {
        isfile = 0;
        xfsrc = stdin;

        if (argc <= 0)
            break;

        xfsrc = fopen(*argv,"r");
        if (xfsrc == NULL) {
            perror(*argv);
            exit(1);
        }

        isfile = 1;
    } while (0);

    // get number of data elements
    int worksize;
    fscanf(xfsrc,"%d",&worksize);

    // get limit [pivot]
    int k;
    fscanf(xfsrc,"%d",&k);

    dbgprt("master: PARAMS worksize=%d k=%d\n",worksize,k);

    // read in the data array
    int *workvet = dataload(xfsrc,worksize);
    if (isfile)
        fclose(xfsrc);

    // get number of workers
    // NOTE: we do _not_ have the master do calculations [for simplicity]
    // usually, for large data, we want the master free to control things
    int numworkers = numproc - 1;

    // get number of elements for each worker
    int workper = worksize / numworkers;

    dbgprt("master: LOOP numworkers=%d workper=%d\n",numworkers,workper);

    // send data to other workers
    int remain = worksize;
    int offset = 0;
    int portion;
    for (workrank = 1;  workrank < numproc;  ++workrank,
        offset += portion, remain -= portion) {
        // get amount for this worker
        portion = workper;

        // last proc must get all remaining work
        if (workrank == (numproc - 1))
            portion = remain;

        dbgprt("master: WORK/%d offset=%d portion=%d\n",
            workrank,offset,portion);

        // send the worker's data count
        sendint(workrank,&portion,1);

        // send the pivot point
        sendint(workrank,&k,1);

        // send the data to worker
        sendint(workrank,&workvet[offset],portion);
    }

    // accumulate count
    int total = 0;
    int count;
    for (workrank = 1;  workrank < numproc;  ++workrank) {
        recvint(workrank,&count,1);
        total += count;
    }

    printf("%d numbers bigger than %d\n",total,k);

    // do cross check of MPI result against a simple single process solution
#ifdef CHECK
    count = docalc(workvet,worksize,k);
    printf("master count was %d -- %s\n",
        count,(count == total) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
#endif
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (myrank == 0)
        master(argc,argv);
    else
        worker();

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually changed `maior` to `highest` to post the issue here, so it would make a bit of sense (maior is greater in portuguese) but failed to do so for all instances, I'm sorry for that. I'm also editing my post to add the problem description.

Comment: I just updated the code without the translation to reflect what I'm working on. So, for the `subvets` part I actually thought of this being a matrix, where I would send each of its lines as being one array to each of the worker threads, and the `if` statement is there to only read up until the size of the array has been reached, thus, leaving the rest of the values as 0 (because I used `calloc`, thus making this approach fit to the problem I have to solve).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I changed my code having in mind a lot that you wrote and from ideas I had while reading your code (insanely well written btw) and now it is working as expected.